# Deleting string from array of strings (C)

Tags: c, string, memory-management, malloc, realloc

I have an array of pointers (char**) which contain some strings. The array ends with an empty string ('\0'). I am supposed to search for a specific word in that array of strings and delete the whole line (ofc using realloc and shortening the array of strings). I'm having hard time doing this, I keep getting 'bad ptr' error.

My code:

```
void deleteSentence(char **text){
    char *word,*fptr;
    int i=0;
    word=(char*)calloc(BUFFER,sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter word to delete sentences:\n");
    gets(word);
    while(text[i][0]!='\0'){
        char *str=(char*)malloc((strlen(text[i])+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(str,text[i]);
        fptr=strtok(str,DELIM);
        while(fptr!=NULL){
            if(strcmp(fptr,word)==0){
                int j=i;
                while(text[j][0]!='\0'){
                    text[j]=(char*)realloc(text[j],(strlen(text[j+1]))*sizeof(char));
                    strcpy(text[j],text[j+1]);
                    j++;
                }
                free(text[j]);
            }
            fptr=strtok(NULL,DELIM);
            if(fptr!=NULL)
                i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Help much appreciated :)

Comment: That the very first thing in this "deletion" code is a `calloc` of a string buffer is *not* a good indication of things to follow. that the very next thing is a call to `gets()` all-but-clinches that forethought.

Comment: *Isolate your code*. this function should have two inputs: the string to delete and the pointer-array-base (by address). The input mechanism has no business being here. It clutters your code and makes it more difficult to manage. (and as a bonus, I see at least two memory leaks already). I don't suppose you ran this in a debugger and stepped through your code to see what was happening at each line?

Comment: My code isn't isolated because its what the function should do (according to the assignment). Yes I did go through the debugger more than once.

Comment: And when the debugger detected the crash, to which line of code was it referencing as the offending culprit? Also, your description is not clear. Does each string in `text[]` refer to an entire sentence? And if so, is that entire sentence to be removed?

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x526ed340 (msvcr100d.dll) in ex3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
I have no idea (using Visual C++ 2010)

Comment: That debugger is one of the finest for application-level programming. What your issue is with using it I have no idea. I don't understand something else. You say the array ends with an empty string. Do you mean a NULL pointer? or a pointer to a string with only one character, the nil-terminator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're leaking memory like a sieve leaks water, and overrunning your arrays in at least two places. Furthermore the integration of input with the functional purpose of this code does literally *nothing* to help. The function should do one thing and one thing only:

> Given a pointer to an array of `char*` pointers terminated with an empty string (or NULL), delete all strings in the pointer array that contain *word*. The resulting potentially compacted array is the return value of the function.

Consider this:

```
char ** deleteSentances(char **text, const char *word)
{
    char **dst = text, **src = text, **res = text;
    size_t size = 1, deleted = 0;

    // loop while we have a non-null string that isn't empty
    while (*src && (*src)[0])
    {
        char *tmp = strdup(*src);
        if (tmp == NULL)
        {
            perror("Failed to allocate tmp");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        char *token = strtok(tmp, DELIM);

        // search for matching word
        while (token && strcmp(word, token))
            token = strtok(NULL, DELIM);

        // if not found, keep the string. otherwise delete it.
        if (!token)
        {
            *dst++ = *src++;
            size++;
        }
        else
        {
            free(*src++);
            ++deleted;
        }

        // don't need this.
        free(tmp);
    }

    // resize the original array (which could have only gotten smaller)
    if (deleted > 0)
    {
        res = realloc(text, size * sizeof(*res));
        if (res == NULL)
        {
            perror("Failed to allocate res");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        res[size-1] = *src;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Hopefully that explains enough. The code is called like this:

```
char **text, *word;

//... populate text with strings
//... populate word with prospect word

text = deleteSentances(text, word);
```

---

**Memory Leaks O'Festival**

The OP wanted to understand where memory leaks were in the original posted algorithm. Consider the following first and foremost: For every allocation, there should be a known point of free'ing that memory. This example is somewhat difficult to nail that concept down simply because you're *bringing* dynamic allocations to the function, and *some* of them are going to be kept.

That said, consider the following places of interest. We assume coming in to this that at some point we allocated a pointer-array of this form:

```
char **text = malloc(N * sizeof(*text));
```

I.e. we have `N` character points. In each of those, we further assume a dynamic allocation for a character string has also transpired:

```
for (int i=0; i<(N-1); ++i)
{
    //... compute length of next string

    text[i] = malloc(length * sizeof(**text));

    //... copy in next string to text[i]

}
```

And finally, the last character pointer in the `text` array is either NULL or points to a dynamic string of length 0 (i.e. a 0-length terminated string).

Whew. Ok. after all of that lets look at your algorithm:

```
void deleteSentence(char **text)
{
    char *word,*fptr;
    int i=0;

    // Leak 1: allocate a single buffer of BUFFER-length.
    //  this is never freed anywhere in this function
    word=(char*)calloc(BUFFER,sizeof(char));

    printf("Enter word to delete sentences:\n");

    // Problem: gets() is so evil and bad it has been deprecated from
    //  the C langage and will not be available in the next release.
    //  use fgets() instead.
    gets(word);

    while(text[i][0]!='\0')
    {
        // Leak 2: Done N times, where N is the number of strings in
        //  your original array. again, this is never freed.
        char *str=(char*)malloc((strlen(text[i])+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(str,text[i]);
        fptr=strtok(str,DELIM);

        while(fptr!=NULL)
        {

            if(strcmp(fptr,word)==0)
            {
                int j=i;
                while(text[j][0]!='\0')
                {
                    // Leak 3: Done M-N times for ever string we find in position
                    //  M of the original array. This can be *huge* if there are
                    //  a decent number of number of reductions that crunch your
                    //  original array down.
                    text[j]=(char*)realloc(text[j],(strlen(text[j+1]))*sizeof(char));
                    strcpy(text[j],text[j+1]);
                    j++;
                }

                // Problem: this just freed the termination string, which should
                //  never be done. We now have undefined behavior for the rest
                //  of this algorithm since the terminatingg string is invalid.
                free(text[j]);

                // Problem: You shoud break right here. See below for why
            }

            // Problem: you're missing an else condition here. At this point
            //  if the strcmp() found a match there is no reason to continue
            //  the loop. You found a match and deleted the string, crunching
            //  all the other string down one slot in a most-inefficient
            //  memory-leaking algorihm.

            fptr=strtok(NULL,DELIM);

            // Problem: the logic here is completely wrong. The i in this case
            //  should be incremented OUTSIDE the inner while loop. Furthermore
            //  the test is backwards.
            if(fptr!=NULL)
                i++;
        }
    }
}
```

In short, if it were possible to leak *more* memory than you did in that algorithm, I'm hard pressed to see how. The posted code I provided will work given the confines of the description I presented, and should be *carefully* looked to, even stepped through with a debugger line-y-line, to better understand how it works.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain, still I have no idea where I'm leaking memory so if you could enlighten me that'd be fantastic.

Comment: @MuliYulzary Just got back from being out. I'll try and type up something if I get a break.